# How to change Url bar with loaded page in Python Using Quickly

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, glade, canonical-quickly

I am really new at Python. I saw tutorial on youtube followed it and created web browser. Now Im trying to add features.
Im using Quickly on ubuntu.
I need to find signal from WebKit wich says page loaded. I will get url address and put it in address bar. Check code I just need figure out how to run that last lines from my code. 
I googled found WebKit Api but it looks different.
Please check code and tell me how to get signal from WebKit. Or how to change address bar with loaded web page url.
Sorry this is my first question and my English is worst.

```
    self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
    self.backbutton = self.builder.get_object("backbutton")
    self.forwardbutton = self.builder.get_object("forwardbutton")
    self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry")
    self.searchentry = self.builder.get_object("searchentry")
    self.scrolledwindow = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow")
    self.toolbar = self.builder.get_object("toolbar")
    self.grid = self.builder.get_object("grid")

    context = self.grid.get_style_context()
    context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)

    self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
    self.scrolledwindow.add(self.webview)
    self.webview.show()




def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.reload()

def on_backbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.go_back()

def on_forwardbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.go_forward()


def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
    url = widget.get_text()
    try:
        url.index("://")
    except:
        url = "http://"+url
    self.urlentry.set_text(url)
    self.webview.open(url)



def on_searchentry_activate(self, widget):
    searchurl  = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="
    searchterm = searchurl + widget.get_text()
    self.webview.open(searchterm)




   Need to find signal for loading this code every time page loads   
    urli = self.webview.get_main_frame().get_uri()
    self.urlentry.set_text(urli)
```

Comment: You could use the `navigation-policy-decision-requested` signal which is documented [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/WebKit-3.0/classes/WebView.html#WebKit.WebView.signals.navigation_policy_decision_requested). That is generally the place where you should look for the documentation.